# Xcode 4 and Interface Builder: Editing Vertical Spacing Constraint (Anchor Top, not Bottom)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xib

I've got a widget that is not laying out correctly on device (its *looks* OK in IB, but its not quite right). The widget is a label and its located about mid-screen. Interface Builder gave it a Vertical Space Constraint with a 'Bottom Anchor'. Here, bottom means bottom of the screen (rather than a widget below, or anchor to top screen).

I'm in the inspector, but I don't see how to change to a top anchor (preferably, to the widget above). I tried reading Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html) and [Editing Constraints](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/AutolayoutEditing.html) in particular, but it was a confusing and did not explain how to make the change (or I missed the discussion - which was 7 sentences).

Below is a screen capture under Interface Builder showing the Vertical Space Constraint anchored to the bottom of the screen. And its attributes leave a lot to be desired - Equal, Constant and Priority don't really help.

[image]

Does anyone know how to edit constraints? Specifically, I want to (1) change a vertical spacer's anchor from bottom *to* top; and (2) anchor against the widget above, and not the top of the screen.

Comment: An annotated screenshot would really help, I think

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Select the "Embedded" and the "Calculated" element together by shift-clicking.

With those two elements selected, use the constraints menu:

[image]

This menu, together with careful selection of elements, is central to happy editing of constraints in IB. In your case, choose the central item, the Pin menu. Choose Vertical Spacing - this will create a new constraint on vertical spacing between your two elements. Alternatively, select a single element and pin "Top space to superview" to pin to the top instead of the bottom.

You can now select and delete the vertical spacing to the bottom of the view. IB wouldn't let you delete this before since you have to have a complete, non-ambiguous set of constraints. After adding your new vertical spacing constraint, you now have this.

To illustrate further, here is an empty view controller, with a single text field which I have dragged on:

[image]

All of the constraints are purple, which means IB has added them for me (they are System constraints) and they can't be removed - they are the minimum constraints needed to position and size the text field.

Now, I'll select the text field, and pin the top space to the superview:

[image]

Now you can see that the two vertical space constraints have changed to blue (they are now user constraints) and they have a thicker appearance in the editor. This means that one of them can be deleted. I select the constraint for the bottom space and hit delete:

[image]

Note that this still has the appearance of a user constraint - but if I try to delete it, IB will automatically recreate the system constraint pinning to the bottom of the superview, getting us back to square one.

I have written about this, and similar autolayout topics, [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/).

Comment: I would gladly give you 100 points for that answer. Stack Overflow needs an ecosystem like a video games.

Comment: is it possible to select a default "flow" layout like Android? I find the occasional Xcode choice to anchor towards the bottom to be bizarre.

Comment: No, you're stuck with the "help" IB gives you I'm afraid!

Comment: Regarding your earlier comment, please see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work ;)

Comment: thanks for the link. I performed a quick scan but nothing jumped out for transferring points. The article itself is very long, and I don't have time to read it at the moment to figure out what I am supposed to do to transfer points to you.

Comment: next question. How do I unlink an exiting Vertical Space Constraint placed by IB? I can't seem to delete them. That is, I follow you instructions and get the VSC I want (mine is colored blue), but the system VSC (colored purple) is still in place; and anchoring to absolute Top or Bottom.

Comment: If it's still coloured purple, then you haven't created enough constraints to allow that one to be removed. It's hard to tell without having your exact xib and the constraints in front of me, but deletable constraints are thicker looking (and blue in the navigator). I'll put in some more images with an example

Comment: Awesome. I will get back to getting you those extra points when I come up for air.

Comment: Last questions. What is the criteria Xcode uses to "top anchor" versus "bottom anchor". It seems haphazard to me, which is further adding to my frustration. For example, in my original capture, why did Xcode *not* choose to pin to the top of the screen or to the label above?

Comment: It looks to me like it just pins to the closest edge of the superview, and will only pin to a peer-level view if you have chosen the recommended spacing (e.g. when the blue dotted line shows up)

Comment: @JeffStone embedded and calculated refer to two specific elements in the question, its not a general thing. It means any two views.

Answer (score -1):

I got one word for Autolayouts. If it works, it works but if it does not, then use the old fashioned way (use code)

Comment: Autolayout can be used in code or interface builder. What are you talking about?

Comment: For a  project  which does not have to be supported on 5.0 and is only designed for ios 6.0, the Autolayout works just fine. But when you have a project which uses old springs and struts and has animation in it, and you turn autolayout, all hell breaks loose. Suddenly, the animation stops working or works incorrectly. the elements are positioned everywhere. So for static contents, using Autolayout may work for you, but for dynamic contents (like animation), you got to rely on using the code to add NSLayoutConstraints and make it look like the version that does not use autolayout