# Top Space Constraint on UIView but not UIImag

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, interface-builder, constraints

I'm having a heck of a time with using some of these constraints. I'm simply trying to add a UIView in the IB so that I can inject other views into as needed. However, I can not get the positioning right. No matter how many Constraints I add or remove I cannot seem to remove the 'Top Space to: Superview'. I'm simply trying to pin the UIView to the bottom and have it float up for the different screen sizes. This 'Top Space' is forcing the UIView off the screen and I can't seem to remove it nor de-prioritize it.

UIView Constraints (doesn't work) - sorry can't post images yet
http://i1322.photobucket.com/albums/u574/dneely79/uiview-constraints_zpscae66ed9.png

On another note though I can remove the UIView and add a UIImageView and I can get this to work. So, for now I'm actually injecting my views into this element instead of a UIView. Its working, just feels dirty.

UIImageView Constraints (Works)
http://i1322.photobucket.com/albums/u574/dneely79/uiimageview-constraints_zps726da545.png

Anyone else have any thoughts on how to overcome this? Its been driving me mad and doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

I've already tried this help link (though trying to anchor bottom and not top)
[Xcode 4 and Interface Builder: Editing Vertical Spacing Constraint (Anchor Top, not Bottom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107799/xcode-4-and-interface-builder-editing-vertical-spacing-constraint-anchor-top)

Thanks ahead of time for any help or advice on this matter.

Comment: Adding a comment since I can't answer it yet. But, my apologies. This was a semi-goofy mistake on my part based on the defaults that IB gives you. I went back and better analyzed my own pictures and noticed a height set on the UIImageView and not UIView. I added a height and was able to successfully delete the Top Space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a semi-goofy mistake on my part based on the defaults that IB gives you. I went back and better analyzed my own pictures.

After noticing a height set on the UIImageView and not UIView, I added a height and was able to successfully delete the Top Space.