# Can you anchor a view in place? (or is there some other work around to preventing a view from being shoved by a UIDateTimePicker?) (iOS)

Tags: ios, slide, uidatepicker, inputview

I added a `UIDatePicker` programmatically, and I set it as the `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` of a `UITextField` so that the date picker pops up instead of the keyboard when selecting the text field.

The date picker pops up; however, the only problem is, it shoves the rest of the view up, thus hiding the `UITextField` that is being changed (since the text field is at the top of the screen).

**Is there any way to prevent this unwanted shoving from occurring?** Or could I somehow anchor the view in place in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method and unanchor the view in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method? (Note: I tried setting the view to the top of the screen in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method by doing `self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);` however this did not do anything, and I think this is because this occurs before the view is shoved up)

If it helps, the delegate view is a `UITableViewController`. I am aware that `UITableViewController`s are pretty restrictive, and maybe this is why it is acting up; however it wasn't letting me use static cells unless I put them in a `UITableViewController` so I had to choose it by default.

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107799/xcode-4-and-interface-builder-editing-vertical-spacing-constraint-anchor-top) and see if that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you should only set the `UIDatePicker` as the `inputView` property of the `UITextField` NOT the `inputAccessoryView` property of the `UITextField`